# How to get Post parameters in Spring MVC controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to get Post parameters in Spring MVC controller but ServletRequestUtils getStringParameters method cannot find this parameter and returns empty array. Is there any way to get array parameter with ServletRequestUtils?

My Controller;

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

    //I can get id parameter without problem.
    String id = ServletRequestUtils.getStringParameter(request, "id", null);

    String[] types = ServletRequestUtils.getStringParameters(request, "types");
}
```

My ajax post;

```
$.post("update", {
   id: id,
   types: types
   ....
}
```

My form-data;

```
id=2a4e905d-8015-447c-9d52-896042367c8a&types%5B%5D=IP+Num&types%5B%5D=Ver+Tab
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding traditional:true to the option like this

```
 $.ajax({
         url:'update',
         type:'post',
         data:{
               id: id,      
               types:types,
              ....
              },
          traditional:true 
        })
```

Or

```
$.post("update",  $.param({
   id: id,      
   types:types,
   ....
  },true)

}
```

Comment: Still cannot find parameter.

Comment: sorry,I updated the answer,i'm sure it will work this time

Comment: I updated my $.post method to $.ajax method and working without any problem now thanks.

Comment: There is a better solution that you can add a parameter `String[] types` to update method , spring mvc will intelligently inject the param for you